# Browser is not storing/sending cookies with new requests

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to make a custom multi step registration system. Should be fairly simple;

1. The frontend (pure Javascript) sends a post requests with fetch that contains the
   desired username and password. This part works fine.
2. The backend (FastAPI) receives the request, do a few things with the post data and return a response containing a unique id as a cookie. This part work as i can see the set-cookie header in the response sent by the server through the Firefox dev tools.
3. When the user fill step 2 of the registration process and click next, a new fetch request is sent to the server along with the cookie containing the unique id which allow the server to keep track of the user through the process. This is where it doesn't work, the frontend is not sending back the cookie in the header of the following request and it doesn't appear under storage > cookie in the dev tools.

Is there something i have to do for Javascript to include cookies in the fetch request? Or is the cookie not registering correctly when first received by the backend? I am stuck, please help.

Here is the frontend code for sending the request for step2 that should include cookies.

```
this.querySelector("[step=\"2\"] button.next").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            var n1 = this.querySelector("#register_email_code1");
            var n2 = this.querySelector("#register_email_code2");
            var n3 = this.querySelector("#register_email_code3");
            var n4 = this.querySelector("#register_email_code4");
            var n5 = this.querySelector("#register_email_code5");
            var n6 = this.querySelector("#register_email_code6");
            // if code is valid
            if (this.validateEmailCode()) {
                // send request
                var code = n1.value + n2.value + n3.value + n4.value + n5.value + n6.value;
                fetch("/register/step2", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                    credentials: 'include',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        "email_code": code,
                    })
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json()
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.status === "success") {
                        // go to step2
                        this.step3();
                    }
                    else if (data.status === "error") {
                        // notification to screen
                        console.log(data.message);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
            else {
                // reset inputs
                n1.reset();
                n2.reset();
                n3.reset();
                n4.reset();
                n5.reset();
                n6.reset();
                console.log("The code entered contains invalid characters.");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it has nothing to do with the fetch request, it's about the domain.
my server was on 127.0.0.1 and my browser on localhost, apparently these are seen as different domain so the cookies were not sent.